# Is there a way to return one or many items without repeating yourself?

Tags: php, arrays

I seem to be stuck. I have a funtion that calculates the salary. I am trying to make it so that I can specify one or many users when I call the function. But I ran into 2 problems. One is how could I construct the output result if I specify multiple user ids. And second problem is how not to repeat my code twice (for one and many users). It works fine if I only need to get it for one user.

I would like to be able to call it like this:

```
// Get salary for user id: 10
$salary = Salary::getSalary([10], '2018-12-01', '2018-12-31');

echo $salary->user->fullname;
echo $salary->salary->total;
echo $salary->checked;

// Get salary for users - 10, 20, 30
$salaries = Salary::getSalary([10, 20, 30, '2018-12-01', '2018-12-31');

foreach ($salaries as $salary) {
    echo $salary->user->fullname;
    echo $salary->salary->total;
    echo $salary->checked;
}
```

**Here is my function**

```
public function getSalary($user_id, $date_from, $date_to)
{
    $salary = new stdClass;

    if ( count($user_id) == 1 ) {
        $salary->user = new stdClass;
        $salary->user->fullname = self::getUserById($user_id)->fullname;
        $salary->user->phone    = self::getPhone($user_id);
        $salary->user->email    = self::getUserById($user_id)->e_mail;

        $salary->salary      = self::getSalary($user_id, $date_from, $date_to);
        $salary->checked     = self::isChecked($user_id, $date_from, $date_to);
    } else if ( count($user_id) > 1 ) {
        foreach ($user_id as $employee) 
        {
            $salary->employee = new stdClass;
            $salary->employee->fullname = self::getUserById($user_id)->fullname;
            $salary->employee->phone    = self::getPhone($user_id);
            $salary->employee->email    = self::getUserById($user_id)->e_mail;
            $salary->employee->siawork  = self::getUserById($user_id)->siawork;

            $salary->salary      = self::getSalary($user_id, $date_from, $date_to);
            $salary->checked     = self::isChecked($user_id, $date_from, $date_to);
        } 
    }

    return $salary;
}
```

Comment: If you always return an array of stdClass, the unique difference between cases are the number of results in it.

Comment: why in one case you use `->user` and in the other `->employee`?

Comment: There's also the issue that in your foreach, you're calling `self::getUserById($user_id)->fullname;` but `$user_id` is an array of all the ID's, you should be calling `self::getUserById($employee)->fullname;`

Comment: @Liga, where are you? I worked hard on an answer and am mildly offended that you haven't responded or commented or accepted any answer. Have you had a chance to try any of these fixes?

Comment: @Stevish sorry, I had to run outside, I did answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if when you call the function and there is only 1 entry, then you can convert this to an array so that you always use the same code to process the data, and build an array of the salary data to send back...

```
public function getSalary($user_id, $date_from, $date_to)
{
    $salaries = [];

    if ( !is_array($user_id) ) {
        $user_id = [$user_id];
    }
    foreach ($user_id as $employee)
    {
        $salary->employee = new stdClass;
        $salary->employee->fullname = self::getUserById($user_id)->fullname;
        $salary->employee->phone    = self::getPhone($user_id);
        $salary->employee->email    = self::getUserById($user_id)->e_mail;
        $salary->employee->siawork  = self::getUserById($user_id)->siawork;

        $salary->salary      = self::getSalary($user_id, $date_from, $date_to);
        $salary->checked     = self::isChecked($user_id, $date_from, $date_to);

        $salaries[] = $salary;
    }

    return $salaries;
}
```

You could if you wish, return a single entry if you want to by amending the last part of the code...

```
    if ( count($user_id) == 1 ) {
        $salaries = $salaries[0];
    }
    return $salaries;
}
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution for your class function. It looks like you were trying to return a single object and overwriting employee every time. If you can accept an array of ID's, it makes sense to return an array of salaries. Does this make sense?

```
public function getSalary($user_id, $date_from, $date_to)
{
    //Return an array of salary objects to match your array of id inputs
    $salary = [];

    if ( ! is_array($user_id) ) {
        //In case a non-array is entered
        $user_id = [$user_id];
    } 

    // A foreach will work even if there's only one user ID given,
    // as long as it's an array (which it should be by this point)
    foreach ($user_id as $id) 
    {
        //Get your salary object by id
        $this_user = new stdClass;
        $this_user->user = new stdClass;
        $this_user->user->fullname = self::getUserById($id)->fullname;
        $this_user->user->phone    = self::getPhone($id);
        $this_user->user->email    = self::getUserById($id)->e_mail;

        $this_user->salary      = self::getSalary($id, $date_from, $date_to);
        $this_user->checked     = self::isChecked($id, $date_from, $date_to);

        //Put it in the output array
        $salary[] = $this_user;
    } 

    return $salary;
}
```

Note, please validate all these inputs! Make sure that putting in something unexpected to `$user_id` or `$date_from` or `$date_to` will not break everything without at least showing an error.

Comment: In case there is only 1 user id specified, I shouldn't have to foreach an array so it shouldn't be a multi dimensional array - only $salary->user->fullname. But if there are multiple user ids then it should be $salary[0]->user->fullname and $salary[1]->salary etc.

Comment: Either way, you need to do some checks at some point to find out whether there is only one or not. For simplicity's sake, it seems wise wto always have the function return the same thing. Running a foreach on an array with only one item in it doesn't add much computational overhead, and it avoids having to check how many entries there are and duplicating some of your code.